# while rotating the label font crispiness missing,how to overcome this issue?

Tags: c#, winforms

Below code i am getting rotation and everything was fine, but only the font crispiness was not getting ,please help .

```
randz.CustomControls.VerticalLabel ctrl = new randz.CustomControls.VerticalLabel();
                ctrl .Text = nodeval;
                ctrl .Name = LableName;
                ctrl .Location = new Point(x, y);
                ctrl .TextDrawMode = randz.CustomControls.DrawMode.BottomUp;
                ctrl .Width = 20;
                ctrl .BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                ctrl .RenderingMode = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
```

Comment: Try the other TextRenderingHints and also play with the SmoothingMode. Also note the crispyness is the opposite of smoothness.

Comment: i tried SystemDefault,AntiAlias,AntialiasGridFit,ClearTypeGridFit,SingleBitPerPixel,SingleBitPerPixelGridFit but the font will be in same manner.

Comment: Font rendering improvement techniques like TrueType hinting and ClearType anti-aliasing were optimized to work well only on horizontal text and are not nearly as effective on vertical text.  Graphics.DrawString() does not help either.  The only possible way to get ahead is to draw bigger, high resolution monitors are readily available today.

Comment: my requirement is to print a template of all vertical text labels  so, what i have to do to overcome the font crispiness?